# 3 ubuntu machines lose eth-connection (and IP) synchronously after some hours

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp, switch, static-ip

Setup:

- some 40-port switches (unmananged) - ip range 192.168.10.x - 255, 192.168.10.1-50 DHCP reserved (~30 used), 51-255 Static IP range (~200 used)
- one brand new 8 port (unmanaged) switch - 3 ubuntu servers (16.04)  connected to it.
- Single WAN connection.

..so i added 3 ubuntu servers to this system..

First DHCP, works well - for some hours, until the network or whoever decides to not renew the lease (probably?) and all machines are no more reachable, at the same time.

Second Static IPs(192.168.10.81 - 83), works well -for some hours! than, synchronously and again, the network (or whoever) decides to drop all 3 servers. Its not the WAN that failed or any device.., just the 3 new servers. Synchronously. When i return, they will be running fine - just without ethernet. After a reboot, everything will be fine again, they'll get their static IP back as if nothing ever happened. then i leave, and after like 12, or maybe sometimes 20 hours - they lose their connection again.

I have no idea what is going on - or what could even go on. 
I ran these servers before in a different network, without any network issues at all.

I'm beginning to consult esotericists about this, if i don't solve this soon. bugs me very.

Lingering questions:

- why does the network drop the machines after some X hours, if they
  optaind an IP via DHCP - should'nt the lease just get renewed?!
- Why can static IPs suddenly disappear from the network? synchronously?
- What are the common pitfalls here? - i have no more ideas where even in theory something could go wrong in such a 'simple'
  environment.

Any help much appreciated,

Comment: Examine the servers. So far the only thing you said about them is "lose their connection", which is _very_ vague. Log in to each server and check whether it still has an IP address assigned; whether it still has the correct routes; whether it can ping the router (or at least resolve it via ARP; arping is a good testing tool); and so on.

Comment: Define "lose eth-connection", "no more reachable" and "without ethernet"? Are they losing their IP? Do they have an IP still but can't reach the gateway (or other devices on the network)? Can they still reach each other or some things on the network but not the Internet? What does the ARP table look like when things are working and when they aren't? Are there issues with any other device on the network? While this question likely wouldn't be on topic at NE, perhaps the [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) will be helpful to improve your question.